# run time error '13' type mismatch

Tags: vb6

I have my query on VB6 which was:

```
Set Db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(App.Path & "\sample4nC4.mdb")

Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("select *from tbl_student;")

Do Until rs.EOF
    With ListView1
        .ListItems.Add , , rs.Fields("stud_ID")
        .ListItems(ListView.ListItems.Count).SubItems(1) = rs.Fields("stud_fname")
        .ListItems(ListView1.ListItems.Count).SubItems(2) = rs.Fields("stud_lname")
        .ListItems(ListView1.ListItems.Count).SubItems(3) = rs.Fields("stud_address")
        .ListItems(ListView1.ListItems.Count).SubItems(4) = rs.Fields("stud_age")
    End With
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

When I execute this query, there was an error on line 2 says:

> Run Time Error '13' Type Mismatch

I really don't get it because when I check the table name, it was correct and yet I cant access the table. Can anybody answer my problem?

Comment: give space after asterisk: "select * from tbl_student". 
What is the exact statement on which Type Mismatch error is thrown ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have references to ADO and DAO in your project?

If so, look at this Microsoft support article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181542

Answer (score 0):

Do these

1. Replace your query from 'select *from tbl_student;' 
   to
   **'select stud_fname, stud_lname, stud_address, stud_age from tbl_student'**

   *This includes (1. space between '*' and 'from'   2. remove ';'    3. specify the field names explicitly)*
2. Put a breakpoint in the first line your program and step into, if it still fails check which line it's failing.